# How to generate the leads and lags matrix for relative time models?

Tags: regression, econometrics, difference-in-difference

I have been struggling with this question for weeks. I would truly appreciate any sort of help.

In my data, I have 150 individuals and 22 time periods (weekly data, so 22 weeks). The individuals are treated somewhere between week 16 ~ week 21 and the control group is never treated. The main result of the difference-in-differences model is significant, meaning that the treatment effect is valid on my dependent variable. However, the relative time model (the leads and lags model) says that my treatment is not significant in any of the weeks.

Below is the equation that I am benchmarking with:

[image]

Here, *Activity_it* is the dependent variable which is log transformed, *α_i* is the individual fixed effects, *τ_t* the time fixed effects, and *T(n,i,t)* refers to the chronological distance of each individual *i* in time *t*.

I understood that *T(n,i,t)* is a series of dummies that indicate the *distance* between the treatment effect and period *t*, so since I have 22 weeks, I have 't-15' to 't+6' (with t-1 being my omitted base), each representing whether or not the specific individual was started being treated in the specific period.

I am solving this model with linear algebra, so I would appreciate if someone would tell me how the matrix of T(n,i,t) would look like. T